# simplest way to return all of the text between a pair of html tags in BeatifulSoup

Tags: python

OK. I have a massive HTML file, and I only want the text that occurs between the tags

```
<center><span style="font-size: 144%;"></span></center>
```

and

```
<dl>  <dd><i></i></dd>  </dl>
```

I am using Python2.6 and Beautifulsoup, but I have no idea where to begin. I'm assuming it's not difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(YOUR_HTML)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
print texts
```

Comment: thanks, @aeby but that doesn't work. i never said i wanted all the text. in fact, i don't want 90% of it. i only want the text that occurs between specific tags. hence my question.